# Integrating $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ without using trigonometry

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry

I am a beginning calculus student. Tonight I had a thought. Maybe I could calculate $\pi$ using integration, but no trig.

The problem is that I don't really know where to start. I thought perhaps I could use the Chain Rule for derivatives.
$~~~~~~~~~$

Comment: If you can integrate $\sqrt{1-x^2}$, you can compute $\arcsin$. So any method for computing $\pi$ by integrating $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ will almost certainly involve something resembling trigonometry, at least in the sense that you could just as easily use it for general trigonometric purposes.

Comment: You could use a Riemann Sum. This is how the definite integral is introduced In beginning calculus textbooks, and the technique can be implemented on a pocket calculator, Excel spreadsheet, or using rudimentary programming.

Answer (score 4):

$\pi$ is a transcendental number. You can't get it in a closed form without using transcendental functions. It's not a value of any algebraic expression (polynomial, rational function, root of polynomial,...) evaluated at any algebraic number. So, you either have to bring $\pi$ into it from the boundaries of the integral, or get it from a transcendental function (trigonometric in this case).

Of course, non-closed form is ok, your original integral is a nice example of that. You could develop your function into an infinite series and try to compute integrals term-by-term. That is actually one of the ways to compute $\pi$ numerically: to construct an infinite sum from such integrals.

We can try the expansion in this case. Consider the series
$$(1+z)^{1/2}=1+\frac{1}{2}z-\frac{1}{2!}\frac{1}{2^2}z^2+\frac{1}{3!}\frac{1\cdot 3}{2^3}z^3-\frac{1}{2!}\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5}{2^4}z^4+\cdots$$
$$(1-x^2)^{1/2}=1-\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{2!}\frac{1}{2^2}x^4-\frac{1}{3!}\frac{1\cdot 3}{2^3}x^6-\frac{1}{4!}\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5}{2^4}x^8+\cdots$$
$$\frac{\pi}{4}=\int_0^1 (1-x^2)^{1/2}dx=1-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{2!}\frac{1}{2^2}\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{3!}\frac{1\cdot 3}{2^3}\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{4!}\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5}{2^4}\frac{1}{9}+\cdots$$
$$\frac{\pi}{4}=1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2n-3)!!}{n! 2^n (2n+1)}$$
where $n!!$ is the double factorial (product of every other term) and by definition $(-1)!!=1$.

The convergence is actually not as bad as in the case of Leibniz formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80), you can actually get a reasonable value.

Answer (score 4):

You could try a Taylor expansion and then integrate.

For example

$$\sqrt{1 - x^2}= 1-\dfrac{1}{2}{{x}^{2}}-\dfrac{1}{8} {{x}^{4}}    -\dfrac{1}{16} {{x}^{6}}  - \dfrac{5}{128} {{x}^{8}} -   \dfrac{7}{256} {{x}^{10}} - \cdots$$

which has an indefinite integral of

$$x-\dfrac{1}{6}{{x}^{3}}-\dfrac{1}{40} {{x}^{5}}    -\dfrac{1}{112} {{x}^{7}}  - \dfrac{5}{1152} {{x}^{9}} -   \dfrac{7}{2816} {{x}^{11}} - \cdots$$

so $$\pi = 4-\dfrac{2}{3}-\dfrac{1}{10}    -\dfrac{1}{28}  - \dfrac{5}{288}  -   \dfrac{7}{704}  - \cdots$$

but convergence is fairly slow with the sum of those particular terms giving about $3.17$

Comment: See my answer for a way to use the same series to get a faster convergence.

Answer (score 3):

**Faster converging series**

$\sqrt{1-x^2} = 1 - \frac{1}{1!} \frac{1}{2} x^2 - \frac{1}{2!} \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2} x^4 - \frac{1}{3!} \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2} \frac{3}{2} x^6 + \cdots$  [by Binomial theorem]

$\ = 1 - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(2k-3)!!}{2^k k!} x^{2k}$  [where $n!!$ is the double-factorial of $n$]

$\int \sqrt{1-x^2}\ dx = x - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(2k-3)!!}{2^k k! (2k+1)} x^{2k+1}$  [which converges faster when $x = \frac{1}{2}$ than $x = 1$]

$π = 12 \cdot \left( \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} \sqrt{1-x^2}\ dx - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{8} \right)$  [the integral is $\frac{1}{12}$ of the pie plus a triangle]

$\ = 12 \cdot \left( \frac{1}{2} - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(2k-3)!!}{2^{3k+1} k! (2k+1)} \right ) - \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2} = 6 - \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2} - 12 \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(2k-3)!!}{2^{3k+1} k! (2k+1)}$

**Notes**

Binomial theorem for non-integer powers can be proven by using Taylor series of $x \mapsto (1+x)^r$ on $(0,1)$. But that requires knowledge of the derivatives, for which the simplest proof is by product rule and chain rule for integer powers, and by implicit differentiation for extending to rational powers, followed by limits for extending to real powers.

Comment: This trick of going from the edge of the convergence radius to the inside, where convergence is better conditioned, is very valuable thing to remember - when it can be done, it helps a lot.

Comment: @orion: Yes indeed. This idea of using a transformation to improve convergence can be used for example to find $\cos^{-1}(x)$ for $x$ close to $1$ using Newton-Raphson. Doing directly makes the rate of convergence increasingly worse as $x$ approaches $1$, but using $\cos^{-1}(x) = \sin^{-1}(1-x^2)$ and inverting $\sin$ gives a uniform quadratic convergence for $x$ bounded away from $0$. Also, the identity $\exp(z2^k) = \exp(z)^{2^k}$ can be used to improve the convergence of the ordinary Taylor series for $\exp$ and costing only $k$ extra multiplications, so one can optimize $k$ based on $z$.

Answer (score 1):

Integrating by parts,

$$I_n=\int(1-x^2)^ndx=(1-x^2)^n\int dx-\int\left[\dfrac{d\{(1-x^2)^n\}}{dx}\int dx\right]dx$$

$$=(1-x^2)^nx+2n\int(1-x^2)^{n-1}x^2\ dx$$

$$=(1-x^2)^nx+2n\int(1-x^2)^{n-1}\{1-(1-x^2)\}\ dx$$

$$I_n=(1-x^2)^nx+2n[I_{n-1}-I_n]$$

$$\implies(2n+1)I_n=(1-x^2)^nx+2nI_{n-1}$$

Set $n=\dfrac12$

But I'm not sure about solving $\int\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ w/o using Trigonometry as $\dfrac{d(\arcsin x)}{dx}=\dfrac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$